# How to create an object in one method and use it in another

Tags: c++, oop

This is the simplified version of my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ClassA {
    public:
        void method1A(){
            cout << "Hello World." << endl;
            }
        void method2A(){
            cout << "Bye." << endl;
            }       
};

class ClassB {
    public:
        void method1B(){
            ClassA objectA;
            objectA.method1A();
            }
        void method2B(){
            objectA.method2A();
            }
};

int main() {
    ClassB objectB;
    objectB.method1B();
    objectB.method2B();
    return 0;
}
```

The error is: ‘objectA’ was not declared in this scope, I suppose it's because the method "method2B" does not have access to the object "objectA" -yep, I'm learning c++ ^^-. How it works without move the "objectA" object declaration from "method1B"?

Comment: If any of the answers helped, please mark it as correct so that people know what worked for you when the have the same question in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the member object outside of your methods:

```
class ClassB {
    public:
        ClassA objectA;
        void method1B(){
            objectA.method1A();
            }
        void method2B(){
            objectA.method2A();
            }
};
```

That way it is accessible to everything inside the class. If you do not want it accessible outside of the class, make it private or protected instead:

```
class ClassB {
    public:
        // Your public declarations
    private:
        ClassA objectA;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I known this option, of course it works, but I need declare the object inside this method. As I said, this is a simplified version of the real code, and in this code can't do that unless change a lot of code...maybe change to "ClassA *objectA = new ClassA;" and use dinamic memory?

Comment: @AngelBravoSaenz You can always give the member variable a new value in `method1B()` so that `method2B()` uses the value created in `method1B()`.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. put `objectA` as a member of `ClassB`
2. create another `ClassA` inside `method2B` (like you did in `method1B`)

Answer (score 1):

You could dynamically allocate space for a new `ClassA` on the heap and then return a pointer to the start of that memory:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class ClassA {
public:
    void method1A(){
        cout << "Hello World." << endl;
    };
    void method2A(){
        cout << "Bye." << endl;
    };       
};

class ClassB {
public:
    ClassA * method1B(){
        ClassA * ObjectA = new ClassA;
        ObjectA->method1A();
        return ObjectA;
    };
    void method2B(ClassA * objectA){
        objectA->method2A();
    };
};

int main() {
    ClassB objectB;
    ClassA * objectA = objectB.method1B();
    objectB.method2B(objectA);
    delete objectA;
    return 0;
};
```

I hope this helped.